# Opencv java interface has no "VideoWriter" class

Tags: java, opencv

official opencv java homepage: http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html
opencv javadoc: http://docs.opencv.org/java/

I just find "VideoCapture" class, but no "VideoWriter" class, so can only capture one frame but can't capture a H.264 video for example.

don't know why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a [known bug](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3453#note-2) . you'll have to wait a bit for it getting fixed.